# Plotting with Flot Chart and using selection based Zoom, causes part of the chart to resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, flot

I am using [flotcharts](http://www.flotcharts.org/). That out of the way I appear to be having a random semi-reproducible issue where every so often when a selection is made, and the chart zooms in. Sometimes the grid area of the chart appears to physically resize, even though I am not apply any different settings or widths to anything. Its some type of glitch in the matrix I can't figure out. Im hoping that someone here might be able to help me sort this out having maybe run into a similar issue.

```
        $(idStr).bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
        console.log(ranges);
        plot_base = a_charts.findBindingPlot('#'+$(this).attr('id'));
        console.log(plot_base);
        if(plot_base !== null && plot_base !== undefined)
        {
            plot = $.plot(plot_base.chart_id, plot_base.chart_data, plot_base.chart_settings);
            $.each(plot.getXAxes(), function(_, axis) {
                var opts = axis.options;
                opts.min = ranges.xaxis.from;
                opts.max = ranges.xaxis.to;

                console.log(opts);
            });
            plot.setupGrid();
            plot.draw();
            plot.clearSelection();
        }
    });
```

Before Zooming:

[image: Initial Render]

After Zooming a couple times getting it to glitch:

[image: After rendered and a few zooms done in attempt to recreate the issue]

Answer (score 0):

In your `plotselected` handler this line:

```
plot = $.plot(plot_base.chart_id, plot_base.chart_data, plot_base.chart_settings);
```

is not needed.  On the selected event you are continuously re-initializing the plot and I'm guessing this is root cause.